# Unable to load the specified metadata resource after adding linq code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Yesterday I had applied code as below in my controller at admin side

```
  public ActionResult Delete(tblGroup Group)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsUpsDelTbl_Group"))
            {
                try
                {
      //Newly added code start
     var grp = db.tblGroups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.GroupID == Group.GroupID);
     if (grp!=null && grp.tblSubGroups.Count>0)
       {
        TempData["AlreadyExist"] = "This Group Name can not be deleted as its enities are bind with SubGroups";
        }
      //Newly added code end
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operation", "Delete");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupID", Group.GroupID);
                        cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                        TempData["Delete"] = "Group Name Deleted Successfully";
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { throw ex; }
            }
        }
        //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

This is to validate that about primary and foreign key relationship and also I given relationship in model and also change the database .
This things were running fine on my local but after updating the database + application on testing server and on clicking of delete it is giving issue as

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your staging connection string change **res://*/Models.ABC.csdl*** to the Connection string on local placed as **res:///Models.XYZ.csdl**

i.e. ABC to XYZ